# refstyle is conflicted with amsmath

Tags: amsmath, refstyle

The problem was discovered when I compile the `unicode-math` document manually. The following code can reproduce this problem.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The console output is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./1.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-01-16>
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)) (./refstyle.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (./refstyle.cfg
! Argument of \eqref  has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.526    lsttxt    = \RSlsttxt}
                               
?
```

Then I found the old version `amsmath` is worked, e.g, [amsmath.sty(2021/10/15 v2.17l)](https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/tex-historic-archive/systems/texlive/2021/tlnet-final/archive/amsmath.tar.xz).

The different is `\DeclareRobustCommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}` and `\newcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}`, i.e., `\eqref` is robust or not.

Question: how can I use `amsmath` and `refstyle` at the same time in the latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked,

> [H]ow can I use `amsmath` and `refstyle` at the same time in the latest version?

Answer: You could load `refstyle` *before* instead of after `amsmath`.

The following code compiles fine under MacTeX2022, `LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1`, `refstyle 2010/11/02 v0.5`, and `amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
test
\begin{equation}\label{a} 1=1 \end{equation}
A cross-reference: \eqref{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. In `refstyle` doc, If the `amsmath` package is loaded, and you define `\newref{eq}` for references to equations, you need to undefine `\eqref` before issuing `\newref` by `\let\eqref=\relax`. So I thought `restyle` would make some changes to `amsmath`, and it was necessary to load `amsmath` first and then `restyle`.

Comment: In addition, can you explain why there is a conflict after the `\eqref` becomes robust?

Comment: @Clara - A general observation: You may want to rethink the wisdom of using the `refstyle` package, which hasn't been updated in more than a dozen years. Instead, consider employing the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package to create sophisticated cross-references. I, for one, think it's easier to keep track of a single cross-referencing command (`\cref`) instead of `\eqref`, `\figref`, `\tabref`, `\secref`, etc.

Comment: Ok, thank you again for your answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've always preferred the refstyle syntax to cleveref but you might be right it's time for a change.

Answer (score 1):

FYI version 0.6 of `refstyle` (2024-01-31) will fix the issue.

Comment: It seems the fix is refstyle 0.6 is not quite correct. This is reported and hopefully will get fixed soon in a new version.