# loading unicode-math then refstyle incompatible with current latex?

Tags: unicode-math, refstyle, eqref

With current LaTeX, it seems the refstyle package (mtime in TL: Nov 2010) cannot be loaded after unicode-math (mtime: Jan 2020), with either xelatex or lualatex. I get `! Argument of \eqref  has an extra }.`, when reading refstyle.cfg.

Loading refstyle first works. Running xelatex from TL22, the original released version, or from older TL's, works. Running xelatex from current (trunk) TL fails.

I guess this was answered here: [refstyle is conflicted with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672975) but the focus there was amsmath. Maybe it's intentional/unavoidable, but it seems like an undesirable compatibility bug to me, so thought I'd post anyway. The document in question for me is the XeTeX reference manual. (Using cleveref instead of refstyle was mentioned there. I don't want to try to figure out what Will was doing with refstyle instead of cleveref. I just want to get the thing updated so I can move on to the next pressing problem.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{refstyle} % loading refstyle first works
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unicode-math loads amsmath, and if this is incompatible with refstyle ... (side remark: in the tagging code we will force amsmath too).

Comment: apart from this: the code errors in refstyle.cfg and it tries there to catch the case that amsmath has already been loaded \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}, so the code of refstyle is wrong there.

Comment: The package doesn't take into account that eqref is robust. `\AddToHook{package/refstyle/before}{\DeclareRobustCommand\eqref{\relax}\let\eqref\relax}` could work as a work around.

Comment: Thank you for all, Ulrike. I wonder if Danie Els (refstyle) author is still contactable/interested ...

Comment: @KarlBerry I contacted Danie and he will take care.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: A fix on the line of the patch below has been included in version 0.6 of `refstyle` (2024-01-31), and thus the issue is fixed in the package now.

I suppose something like this needs to be changed in `refstyle.cfg` (EDIT: patch fixed):

```
--- /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refstyle/refstyle.cfg
+++ /home/juergen/texmf/tex/latex/testen/refstyle.cfg
@@ -511,10 +511,9 @@
       lsttxt    = \RSlsttxt}
 %%-- TEMPLATE FOR EQUATIONS ---------------------
 \newcommand*{\RSeqrefform}[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}
-\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}%
-   {\let\AMSeqref\eqref
-    \let\eqref\relax}%
-   {}
+\AddToHook{package/amsmath/after}%
+   {\NewCommandCopy\AMSeqref\eqref
+    \DeclareRobustCommand\eqref{\relax}}%
 \newref{eq}{%
    name      = \RSeqtxt,
    names     = \RSeqstxt,
@@ -528,9 +527,8 @@
 \let\eqref\relax
 \AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}%
-      {\RS@ifundefined{AMSeqref}{\let\AMSeqref\eqref}{}%
-       \let\RSeqrefform\AMSeqref}%
-         {}%
+      {\DeclareCommandCopy\RSeqrefform\AMSeqref}%
+      {}%
      \let\eqref=\RSeqref
    }
 %%-- TEMPLATE FOR FIGURES -----------------------
```

Comment: It seems the fix is refstyle 0.6 is not quite correct. This is reported and hopefully will get fixed soon in a new version (which basically uses the patch above (with `\DeclareRobustCommand\eqref{\relax}}` rather than `\RS@removedef{eqref}}`)